# How to use EditText over a ImageView

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I am making an application in which i have to use two images in one XML file. ( one is for logo and another is some login pattern) . On the pattern image, I have to set two EditText. How can i do this???

```
     <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical" >
<ImageView
.
.
.
.
./>

          <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:background="@drawable/some image" 
            android:layout_marginLeft="200dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="300dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="80dp">  

           <LinearLayout 
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center" 
            android:orientation="vertical">
            <EditText 
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                           />
        </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
    </relativeLayout>
```

Comment: You want to have a few EditTexts above a background?

Comment: yes... 2 EditText for login ID and Passwrd

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I am understanding this correctly, you essentially want to have a background with two EditTexts in the foreground.

The best way to do this is via a relative layout. Something like this would work (Note, this is pseudo-code, so it won't work directly)

```
<RelativeLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:height="fill_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/some_image"
        android:width="fill_parent" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edit_text1"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edit_text2 "
        android:layout_above="@id/edit_text1" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: actually , there is not anly one image in XML.. there are 2 images in same XML. one is in top right and another one is in bottom left. so i want to set the edit text in top right image..

Comment: Even easier. You can align the EditText to be in the top right image.

Comment: thnx brother.. i have got the results.. :)

Answer (score 1):

Your question is a little vague, but you can easily use [Relativelayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.html) to place the EditTexts above your ImageView.

A basic example is:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/image" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: plz see my code in the end and tell me if I am doing this right??

Comment: sorry i cant answer my question becoz dont have much reputation.. :'(

Comment: Click "edit" in the lower-left corner of your question to add the code there.

Comment: done... plz chk the code

Answer (score 0):

To place edittext above an imageview:

```
EditText edit = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.YOUR_EDITTEXT_ID);
ImageView image = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.YOUR_IMAGEVIEW_ID);
image.setImageBitmap(YOUR_BITMAP);
edit.bringToFront();
```

The above code will bring the edittext above the imageview along the z-axis. Of course, you have to position them either in XML or programmatically.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you every one for your help. I have completed my task..This application is for tablets so plz chk the margines according to that. here is the code..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="#fff"

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/login"
    android:layout_width="648dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="640dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_login" />

<EditText 
    android:id="@+id/et1"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:cursorVisible="true"
    android:background="#000"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="710dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="193dp"
    android:textColor="#fff"/>

<EditText 
    android:id="@+id/et1"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:cursorVisible="true"
    android:background="#000000"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="127dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="710dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="193dp"
    android:textColor="#fff"/>

<ImageView 
     android:id="@+id/logo"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="420dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_glogo" />


 </RelativeLayout>
```